# Methods to extract sucrose from tea after it's been stirred in?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions, extraction

Sugar is often labelled  "white poison" now-a-days and a lot of negative health consequences happen due to increased sugar consumption.

Keeping this in mind, if I were handed a cup of tea (with sugar already stirred in), what methods/processes can I employ to separate/remove the sugar from it?

Comment: Why would you add "white poison" to your tea or other foods in the first place if you want to reduce sugar in your diet? Seriously, you're not going to find an after-the-fact means of reducing sugar content that is remotely as cheap, simple and safe as using low-sugar foods to begin with.

Comment: The best way is to buy some green or black tea as you prefer and drink it alone. Then you don't need to drink other chemicals you used to removed the sugar... also if you like lemon tea or vanilla tea but a lemon or vanilla and use it as flavour for you tea. Now you can still ask [GIVAUDAN](https://www.givaudan.com/flavours/world-flavours/tasteessentials/tea) to get the perfect tea.

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C I always prefer to have green tea or coffee without suger. Question is about some chemical methods to solve a problem. Please look into my improved question with clear use case.

Comment: Have to wait for an hour? All taste of hot served tea will be gone. :( But anyway, thanks for your practical solution suggestions. :)

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40905/is-it-possible-to-separate-remove-sugar-from-common-drinks-such-as-juice

Comment: Add yeast and lt it ferment the sugar