# Any way that I can extract sugar from drinks? Without boiling the drinks

Tags: nanotechnology

Any method? Materials, engineering, any technology.
I am a product design student, so any possible method is useful to me.
I am thinking to add this kind of technology into my concept.

Comment: Pragmatically, it isn't possible...

Comment: If you have the money for a reverse osmosis machine, maybe.

Comment: What is a reverse osmosis machine @@?

Comment: We're gonna need some more details about what the goal is here. Is it okay if the sugar is poisonous to people after extraction (I can think of two techniques that do this)? Does it need to be dried later on? What if the process costs billions of dollars to work on a single can of soda? Is that acceptable? What if it's relatively cheap but takes a few months?

Comment: @MichaelYan You take a filter that lets water through, but not salt or sugar, then apply pressure to squeeze all the water from one side to the other. Salts, sugars, and other things get left on the first side. The problem is that this is *very* expensive and you still have to do a bit more extraction after it's finished.

Comment: @chipbuster ya thats what a want but is that possible that I can block the melted sugar in the water by using a filter? Do you have any related source and link that I can take a look :)

Comment: If by boiling you mean heating, then you could apply vacuum until the water was gone, or let it air dry.

Comment: It's possible to freeze out the water and get the crystals of sugar that separate out

Comment: Of course there is a way: the millennia-old nanotechnology known as yeast fermentation. It has a side effect of producing alcohol, though.

Comment: Already asked https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75160/methods-to-extract-sucrose-from-tea-after-its-been-stirred-in